# How can get a datetime from DayOfWeek and WeekOfMonth?

Tags: c#

I have DayOfWeek and WeekOfMonth, I want to use two values to get a datetime.

For Example: DayOfWeek = 2 (Tuesday), WeekOfMonth = 3 (Third week in month)

```
public DateTime GetDateTime(int year, int month, int dayOfWeek, int weekOfMonth)
```

I want have a method above to handle and return the datetime.
How can I get that datetime?

Comment: If I understand clearly, this is not possible. There is no way to get from these values to number of month and year values.

Comment: There are too many contributing factors which you haven't confirmed - for example, what day do you consider "start of the week"? This can vary depending on location/timezone. This can be done but we need more information.

Comment: Do you want to arrive at a Date object with year,month,dayofweek, weekofmonth passed?

I'm afraid you can't get the time. With some logic, date can be calculated, with a few assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Would this snippet help you?

```
public DateTime GetDateTime(int year, int month, int dayOfWeek, int weekOfMonth)
{

     var date = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
     var temp = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
     var day = 7 - (temp - 1) + ((weeks - 2) * 7) + dayOfWeek;

     return new DateTime(year, month, day);
}
```

If you have week 3, then week 1 and 2 are 7 days each. Adding the dayOfWeek will give you the day of month.

Comment: That's right. I've edited my answer to calculate the days in first week.

Answer (score 0):

First at all, you must know wich day start the month. Then calculate the day you want is easy.

**Code :**
May be, for you, the week doesn't start on Sunday, but on Monday. So, you create a enum that will help us to do all cases :

```
internal enum StartingWeek
{
    WeekBeginWithSunday,
    WeekBeginWithMonday
};
```

Then, just calculate, carrefully with starting day on the week.

```
private static DateTime GetDateTime(int year, int month, DayOfWeek dayofweek, int weekofmonth, StartingWeek start = StartingWeek.WeekBeginWithSunday)
{
    DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

    // ajust calcul with starting day on the week
    int delta = start == StartingWeek.WeekBeginWithMonday ? 1 : 0;

    int durationOfFirstWeek = (7 - (int)firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek + delta) % 7;

    int day = durationOfFirstWeek + (weekofmonth - 2) * 7 + ((int)dayofweek + 7 - delta) % 7 + 1;

    // day is on the previous month
    if (day <= 0)
    {
        return new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    }

    if (day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
    {
        return new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }

    // day is on next month
    return new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month));
}
```

I decide to return for the exception first or last day of the month, but you can do what you want for these cases.

**Testing :**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int year = 2014;
    int month = 10;
    DayOfWeek dayofweek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
    int weekofmonth = 2;
    DateTime date = GetDateTime(year, month, dayofweek, weekofmonth);
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToShortDateString());

    DateTime date2 = GetDateTime(year, month, DayOfWeek.Monday, 1, StartingWeek.WeekBeginWithMonday);
    Console.WriteLine(date2.ToShortDateString());

    DateTime date2b = GetDateTime(year, month, DayOfWeek.Saturday, 1, StartingWeek.WeekBeginWithMonday);
    Console.WriteLine(date2b.ToShortDateString());

    DateTime date2c = GetDateTime(year, month, DayOfWeek.Saturday, 2, StartingWeek.WeekBeginWithMonday);
    Console.WriteLine(date2c.ToShortDateString());

    DateTime date2d = GetDateTime(year, month, DayOfWeek.Sunday, 1, StartingWeek.WeekBeginWithMonday);
    Console.WriteLine(date2d.ToShortDateString());

    DateTime date2e = GetDateTime(year, month, DayOfWeek.Sunday, 2, StartingWeek.WeekBeginWithMonday);
    Console.WriteLine(date2e.ToShortDateString());

    DateTime date3 = GetDateTime(year, month, DayOfWeek.Saturday, 5, StartingWeek.WeekBeginWithMonday);
    Console.WriteLine(date3.ToShortDateString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Output (french format)**

```
11/10/2014
01/10/2014
04/10/2014
11/10/2014
05/10/2014
12/10/2014
31/10/2014
```

Comment: In some cases, the datetime is returned that is not correct. For example: The last Saturday of month or the first Sunday of month

Comment: First sunday of March 2014 : `GetDateTime(year, month, 7, 1)` return 02 March 2014. That's correct. Last saturday of March 2014 : `GetDateTime(year, month, 6, 5);` return 29 March 2014. That's correct too.

Comment: @user3488813 for wich day you have a problem. Seems you don't call right parameters ...

Comment: @user3488813 ok, understood your problem. In some country, week doesn't start with same day. I update the code to cover this case.